# Unable to get frames at 60fps using android native camera API

Tags: android-ndk, android-camera2

I am new to android and I need to capture frames at 60fps for RTSP streaming.
I am using Android native camera API and reading frames on onImageAvailable callback of AImageReader.
ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES returns : {15,15}, {20,20}, {24,24}, {30,30}, {7,30}.
If I try to explicitly set fps range to {30,60} via ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, I can see only 30 frames in a sec in onImageAvailable callback.

Please share opinion on how we can achieve 60fps using AImageReader for YUV frames

Answer (score 0):

ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES returns your only available choices. {30,60} is not one of your choices.

Comment: Is there a way to capture images at more than 30fps then?

Comment: There are a few Android phones capable of 60 fps.  Google pixel and Moto G7 are two that I am aware of.  I have a Samsung S20 FE that I bought in 2020 and it is only capable for 30 fps.  At the Java level, there is a CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession that can give you much higher fps.  But as the name states, it is constrained.  You can preview or record the data but you cannot attach and ImageReader to it.  If you try, it will exception out.

Comment: Thanks Jrog. I am using Samsung Galaxy S9+. Can you please let me know how can I confirm that this device is only capable of 30fps and not higher?

Comment: ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES confirms what your device is capable of.  You can verify your FPS by counting the images as they go through your imagereader.

Comment: Thanks Jrog. I was able to get the expected observations by counting images in imagereader